# Get json data in ajax from PHP object

Tags: php, ajax

I have the javascript shown using ajax code. I used WordPress code to ajax URL and data all things it works when I don't use PHP class(when the input name is empty). But when I use PHP class it returns me the error shown below. I want to know how to call JSON data from the php object using ajax code.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bsnNameEmpty' of undefined.**

**Update** ajax code edit only

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#contactForm img').hide();
function isEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
$('#contactForm').submit(function(event) {
    var bsnname    = $('#bsnname').val();
    var bsnsubject = $('#bsnsubject').val();
    var bsnemail   = $('#bsnemail').val();
    var bsnmessage = $('#bsnmessage').val();
    if ( !bsnname || (bsnname.length < 5) || !bsnsubject || (bsnsubject.length < 1) || !bsnemail || !isEmail(bsnemail) || !bsnmessage || (bsnmessage.length < 5) ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {action: 'bsn_ajax'},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnNameEmpty) {
                $('#name-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnNameEmpty + '</em>');
            }
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnNameLength) {
                $('#name-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnNameLength + '</em>');
            }
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnSubjectEmpty) {
                $('#subject-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnSubjectEmpty + '</em>');
            }
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnSubjectLength) {
                $('#subject-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnSubjectLength + '</em>');
            }
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnEmailEmpty) {
                $('#email-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnEmailEmpty + '</em>');
            }
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnEmailFormat) {
                $('#email-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnEmailFormat + '</em>');
            }
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnMessageEmpty) {
                $('#message-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnMessageEmpty + '</em>');
            }
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnMessageLength) {
                $('#message-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnMessageLength + '</em>');
            }
        });
    }
    if (bsnname && (bsnname.length > 4) && bsnsubject && (bsnsubject.length > 1) && bsnemail && isEmail(bsnemail) && bsnmessage && (bsnmessage.length > 4) ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {action: 'bsn_ajax'},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#name-field em').fadeOut(1);
                $('#subject-field em').fadeOut(1);
                $('#email-field em').fadeOut(1);
                $('#message-field em').fadeOut(1);
                $('#contactForm img').show();
                $('button').text('Sending...');
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#success-msg').html('<p class="bg-success">'+ data.bsnMessageSent +'</p>');
        })
        .always(function(data) {
            document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
            $('#contactForm img').hide();
            $('#success-msg p').fadeOut(5000);
            $('button').text('Send message');
        });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

and i have below php object that i retrived json data from it to ajax response

```
<?php
class YPE_Bsn_Ajax {

function YPE_bsn_conatctus() {
    $bsnContactErrors  = array();
    $bsnContactSuccess = array();

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        if(empty($_POST['bsnname'])) {
            $bsnContactErrors['bsnNameEmpty'] = 'Name is required';
        }

        if(!empty($bsnContactErrors)) {
            $bsnContactSuccess['bsnSuccess'] = false;
            $bsnContactSuccess['bsnErrors']  = $bsnContactErrors;
        } else {
            $bsnContactSuccess['bsnSuccess'] = true;
            $bsnContactSuccess['bsnmessageSent']  = 'Yor email has been sent';
        }
        echo json_encode($bsnContactSuccess);
    }
}
}
$Bsn_ajax = new YPE_Bsn_Ajax();
?>
```

Comment: console.log(data); on done what does it say ?

Comment: don't show anything on done.

Comment: use $.parseJSON(data) to use json data

Comment: @Poria how I can use it please explain it to me

Comment: .fail(function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (!data.bsnSuccess) {
            if(data.bsnErrors.bsnNameEmpty) {
                $('#name-field').html('<em class="text-danger">' + data.bsnErrors.bsnNameEmpty + '</em>');
            } 
        }
    });

Comment: @Poria i used also caught me error say Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111458/discussion-between-poria-and-shwan-namiq).

Comment: Add a `console.log(data);` just after this line: `.fail(function(data) {`. Open firebug/chrome devtools (shortcut F12), and show us what you have.

Comment: @Felippe Duarte doesn't show anything in console but in network in ajax request show 0

Comment: sorry Felippe show this error below Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"bsnSuccess":false,"bsnErrors":{"bsnNameEmpty":"N…uired","bsnMessageEmpty":"Message is required"}}0", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: try `data.responseText.bsnErrors.bsnNameEmpty`

Comment: @ Felippe Duarte also same error not solved my problem

Comment: Where do you print `$bsnContactSuccess` and `$bsnContactErrors`? Do you ever return it to the browser? Do you even call the `->YPE_bsn_conatctus()` function?

Comment: Oh sorry, i missed this line echo json_encode($bsnContactSuccess); now I edit my code and add the line. no, i don't call the function after class instantiation.

Comment: The class needs to be instantiated for the code to run in the first place. You can see that your code is returning nothing in your network tab in your browser (google "<browsername> network tab" and find out how to see it in your browser). You're also only printing `$bsnContactSuccess` but you're only setting the `bsnNameEmpty` key in `$bsnContactErrors` if something goes wrong, so it's not certain that it'll exist. It also seems that you're not including `bsnname` in your POST data?

Comment: @h2ooooooo also in my code have email subject and message input fields but only I put name field because I don't want more code until anyone image my error when. if we say only I have that code in my question how we can solve the error please help me and correct errors for me because I don't have more information about objects

Comment: @ShwanNamiq I was refering to `data: {action: 'bsn_ajax'},` where you're only passing through a `action` key. If this is just for SO, then don't worry about it. That said, what does your server respond if you look in the network tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111463/discussion-between-shwan-namiq-and-h2ooooooo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set headers on the server side for json like so

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($bsnContactSuccess);
```

and then read in javascript

```
$my_data = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log($my_data.responseText.bsnErrors.bsnNameEmpty);
```

and in your server side code add else below this if

```
if(empty($_POST['bsnname'])) {
    $bsnContactErrors['bsnNameEmpty'] = 'Name is required';
} else {
     $bsnContactErrors['bsnNameEmpty'] = 'Name is valid';
}
```

Hope it helps !